# Permission Denied running find command

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I'm running this command:

```
cleber@ubuntux:~$ find . -name "*log*" -name "*2016*"
./log-2016-05-04.txt
./log-2016-05-03.txt
./log-2016-05-08.txt
./log-2016-05-02.txt
./log-2016-05-05.txt
find: ‘./.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
./log-2016-05-01.txt
./log-2016-05-06.txt
./log-2016-05-09.txt
./log-2016-05-07.txt
./log-2016-05-10.txt
find: ‘./.dbus’: Permission denied
```

Why am I getting the "Permission denied" error? All my permission setting on `/home/cleber` are set correctly. 
Someone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: @George It's not a good idea to excursively change permissions in system generated folders. Many of them requires restricted rigths to function correctly.

Comment: @George [`chmod 777` is like Vodka](https://i.imgur.com/GsBeSze.jpg), first you think it solves all your problems, but soon you'll wake up with a massive headache. Avoid it.

Comment: If he has issues in his `/` that's a different matter but in his `/home` directory it should be so. All files and folders there should be _accessible_ to the owner [in this case Holanda].

Comment: @ByteCmmander, yes I was using that as an example as to how to use `-R` option to set permissions deep in the folder not asking he use that. Holanda please take note.

Comment: @George all files should be accessible and being owned by the home directory owner, this mean at least 644 for files and 755 for folders but even that is very broad setting, remember that the second digit is for group and the other is for ALL others, I personally wouldn't go for such a risk and simply 777 all files.  Please look [here for a refresher on permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php).

Comment: @Videonauth, I didn't mean it _literally_ was just for illustrations. Ok I will get rid of the comment, sorry guys.

Comment: @George it wasn't for being mean to you, just think who all reads it, and there are already to many people out there who believe 777 is the norm setting :)

Comment: @Videonauth, Yes I felt that way too that's why I got rid of it, lest some one uses it.

Comment: Thank you guys @George now I clearly understand some files can't be owned by the user even located at /home/cleber

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have some folders with incorrect owners (or maybe permissions) in your home directory.

The `Permission denied` warning means that `find` could not search in a specific folder because it did not have the permissions to list its content, obviously.

In your home directory, the most likely cause is that you were running some GUI applications with `sudo` that messed up file ownerships. To fix this and make you the owner of all files in your home directory again, run this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~
```

Otherwise, if you are sure all permissions and ownerships are correct and you don't want to modify anything, you can also just hide the warning from the output by appending a STDERR redirection to `/dev/null` to your find command:

```
find . -name "*log*" -name "*2016*" 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Do all files and folders  (including ~/.cache/dconf) in the home folder should be owned by the user (in a freshly installed operating system)?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, that's my understanding. I don't know of any exception so far.